# Lookup VS Lookup with pipeline MongoDB (Performace & How it internally works)

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, lookup, nosql-aggregation

I'm making a blog and have an query about which would give me better performace, simple lookup or lookup with pipeline because sometime simple lookup gave me fast result and sometime pipleline lookup. So, I am bit confused now which one to use or where to use. Suppose I have 2 collection, user and comment collection.

```
// Users Collection
{
   _id: "MONGO_OBJECT_ID",
   userName: "Web Alchemist"
}
// Comments Collection
{
   _id: "MONGO_OBJECT_ID",
   userId: "USER_MONGO_OBJECT_ID",
   isActive: "YES", // YES or NO
   comment: "xyz"
}
```

Now I want to Lookup from users collection to comments, which one would be better for this. I made two query which giving me same result.

```
[
    {
        $match: { _id: ObjectId("5d68c019c7d56410cc33b01a") }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "comments",
            as: "comments",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "userId"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$comments"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "comments.isActive": "YES"
        }
    }, 
    { $limit: 5},
    {
        _id: 1, userName: 1, comments: { _id: "$comments._id", comment: "$comments.comment"}
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            userName: { '$first': '$userName' },
            comments: { $addToSet: "comments"}
        }
    }
]
```

***OR***

```
[
    {
        $match: { _id: ObjectId("5d68c019c7d56410cc33b01a") }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "comments",
            as: "comments",
            let: { userId: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: ['$userId', '$$userId'] },
                                { $eq: ['$isActive', 'YES'] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                { limit: 5 },
                {
                    $project: { _id: 1, comment: 1 }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```